# C# Filter List of Objects With a Simple List

Tags: c#, linq

Quite new to LINQ here and I am wondering how to achieve this. I have the following codes:

```
var allOrgs = (from org in this.Context.Organizations select org).ToList();

var childOrgs = (from oc in this.Context.OrganizationChild select oc).ToList();

var parentOrgs = (from op in this.Context.OrganizationParent select op).ToList();
```

the return values for each variable as follows:

```
allOrgs = [{id=1}, {id=2}, {id=3}, {id=4}];
childOrgs = [{id=2}];
parentOrgs = [{id=3}];
```

I want to filter the allOrgs such that only those items that are not in the childOrgs or parentOrgs would be returned, i.e.

```
filteredList = [{id=1}, {id=4}];
```

I have the following LINQ filter (which I need some help with):

```
var filteredList = allOrgs.Where(a => childOrgs.Any(c => c.id != a.id));

filteredList = filteredList.Where(f => parentOrgs.Any(p => p.id != f.id));

return filteredList.ToList();
```

For some reason, I still end up getting all the values...

Appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just merge the two conditions:

```
filteredList = allOrgs.Where(a => !childOrgs.Any(c => c.id == a.id)
                               && !parentOrgs.Any(c => c.id == a.id) 
                            );
```

Note that your original query is backwards - it is looking for all orgs where *any* parent or child org doesn't match.

Comment: I have created a demo (http://ideone.com/o6aQSI) for the sake of simplicity I have just have one class Organization with childOrgs, parentOrgs and allOrgs.

Comment: @Habib add a second item to either list and you'll see that it doesn't work.  I don't know if that is the case with the original code but the logic in the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) for that:

```
var filteredList = allOrgs.Except(parentOrgs).Except(childOrgs).ToList();
```

Comment: That assumes that the default equality for `Organization` compares the `Id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [@DStanley Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022854/961113)...

You can *also* do:

```
var filteredList = allOrgs.Where(a => !childOrgs.Select(r => r.id).Contains(a.id)
                                    && !parentOrgs.Select(r => r.id).Contains(a.id));
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://ideone.com/3D7Oxp)